# Nodejs Web Application in windows

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am new to NodeJS. I have created a web application (it runs at https://localhost:4321) in a Windows server machine using npm, gulp etc. How do I host it in the server. That is I want to open the app in the browser without having to use nodejs through command prompt and using "gulp serve" etc.

Comment: Try gulp build.

Comment: i mean... you've gotta start the app one way or another. Whether it be through the cmd prompt directly, or by creating a windows service that does it. Not really a programming question.

Comment: I think that he means 'deploying app to a server'

Comment: @FieryCod the title of the question is *"Nodejs Web Application **in windows**"*

Comment: Yep but the content of a question shows that he means deploying. He asked 'how do I host it in the server'.

Comment: Right, and windows has iis, can run apache, and you can run node without having either. server doesn't just mean cloud.

Comment: @Kevin B yes you are right sorry my fault

Comment: Thanks Kevin B for clearing the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to host your node.js app locally on Iis server on Windows machine you should definitely take a look into this [project.](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)

Comment: Thanks, what are the other options apart from Heroku? Is there anyway to host it in like an iis server?

Comment: Now I am confused you want to host your app locally or on the remote server?

Comment: yes.. I want to host it locally on my windows server machine

Comment: So my answer is incorrect because it refers to deploying app on the server rather than hosting app locally, please mark my answer as an unanswered, because I want to delete it

Comment: @user3759018 take a look at my new answer, now it is correct

Comment: Thanks FieryCod...will try it